# How to perform an http request to another server from spring boot controller

Tags: java, spring, http, get, get-request

How do I perform a GET HTTP request from my spring boot application hosted on `localhost:8080` on a server hosted on `localhost:80`.

For example, how do I get an image hosted at `locahost:80/image.jpg` from my spring application?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are two ways you can make a third party external api request.

1. RestTemplate

   ```
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

        String uri = localhost:80; // or any other uri

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setAccept(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
        headers.add("user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.99 Safari/537.36");

        HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<>("parameters", headers);
        ResponseEntity<?> result =
                restTemplate.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.GET, entity, returnClass);
        return result.getBody();
   ```

If you want to get images then use following method:

```
String url = "http://img.championat.com/news/big/l/c/ujejn-runi_1439911080563855663.jpg";
byte[] imageBytes = restTemplate.getForObject(url, byte[].class);
Files.write(Paths.get("image.jpg"), imageBytes);
```

You will also need to configure ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter in application config:

```
@Bean
public RestTemplate restTemplate(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> messageConverters) {
    return new RestTemplate(messageConverters);
}

@Bean
public ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter byteArrayHttpMessageConverter() {
    return new ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter();
}
```

2. Unirest
   Add unirest dependency in pom:

```
<!-- Unirest java -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.mashape.unirest</groupId>
      <artifactId>unirest-java</artifactId>
      <version>${unirest.java.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Code to call api:

```java
HttpResponse<JsonNode> jsonResponse = Unirest.get(your_get_url_in_string)
                    .header("header_string", "header_value")
                    .queryString("query", "query_if_any")
                    .asJson();
JsonNode responseBody = jsonResponse.getBody();
```

Comment: This return a Json/string format, what if i want an image instead?

Comment: And i bet i should even change the signature of restTemplate.exchange. The third parametr is a "returnClass", what i should change for image?

Comment: Sorry i keep not understing. Where it is saving the image? Where i can edit "application config"

Comment: It will save image in the Path that you will specify in Paths.get() and create a new java class and annotate it with @Configuration. Any Beans that you put inside that will be added to application config.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to send a request with spring you can do

```
//first create e restemplate variable
RestTemplate restTemplate=new RestTemplate();

//you can create and edit header
HttpHeaders header= new HttpHeaders();
header.add("Authorization", "*****************");
header.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);
header.add("Accept", "application/json");

//you can create and edit body to
MultiValueMap<String, String> body= new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>();
body.add("grant_type", "client_credentials");

HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>> requeteHttp =new HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>>(body, header);

//After you can create a request
ResponseEntity<Response_class> reponse = restTemplate.postForEntity("your api link", requeteHttp , Response_class.class);
//if you want to send a get request you can edit postForEntity to get
```

About Response_class
if you know the return type of the request, you can create a class and use it here, otherwise you can use string instead

if your request returns a json like this

```
{
    "token_type":"***",
    "access_token":"***",
    "expires_in":"***",
}
```

you can create a Response_class controller(class) and call it like we did above otherwise you can use string instead

```
public class Response_class{
    private String token_type;
    private String access_token;
    private String expires_in;

    public Response_class(String token_type, String access_token, String expires_in) {
        this.token_type = token_type;
        this.access_token = access_token;
        this.expires_in = expires_in;
    }

    public Response_class() {
    }

    public String getToken_type() {
        return token_type;
    }

    public void setToken_type(String token_type) {
        this.token_type = token_type;
    }

    public String getAccess_token() {
        return access_token;
    }

    public void setAccess_token(String access_token) {
        this.access_token = access_token;
    }

    public String getExpires_in() {
        return expires_in;
    }

    public void setExpires_in(String expires_in) {
        this.expires_in = expires_in;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [WebClient](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web-reactive.html#webflux-client):

```
byte[] image = WebClient.create("locahost:80/image.jpg")
        .get()
        .accept(MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG)
        .retrieve()
        .bodyToMono(byte[].class)
        .block();
```